# Proceso de xls a xlsx cambia formato de fecha

Tags: java, apache-poi

Tengo un problema al convertir archivos xls a xlsx y es que al momento de leer las celdas donde tienen las fechas el tipo de dato en la celda del xls figura como 13/04/2016 (El tipo de dato en el documento dice personalizado) pero cuando genero el nuevo documento en xlsx me lo toma como un numero por ejemplo 14690 y al formatearlo me da una fecha erronea, como puedo hacer para que en la lectura de esa celda lo tome como un simple string y que no lo convierta a int ? dejare el codigo que hace la conversion de xls a xlsx?

```
public class xls2xlsx {

/**
 * @param archivo
 * @param salida
 * @throws InvalidFormatException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String convertirLibro(String archivo,String salida) throws InvalidFormatException,
        IOException {

    String inpFn = archivo;
    String outFn = salida;

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inpFn));
    try {
        Workbook wbIn = new HSSFWorkbook(in);
        File outF = new File(outFn);
        if (outF.exists())
            outF.delete();

        Workbook wbOut = new XSSFWorkbook();
        int sheetCnt = wbIn.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < sheetCnt; i++) {
            Sheet sIn = wbIn.getSheetAt(0);
            Sheet sOut = wbOut.createSheet(sIn.getSheetName());
            Iterator<Row> rowIt = sIn.rowIterator();
            while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
                Row rowIn = rowIt.next();
                Row rowOut = sOut.createRow(rowIn.getRowNum());

                Iterator<Cell> cellIt = rowIn.cellIterator();
                while (cellIt.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cellIn = cellIt.next();

                    Cell cellOut = rowOut.createCell(
                            cellIn.getColumnIndex(), cellIn.getCellType());

                    switch (cellIn.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getErrorCellValue());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                        cellOut.setCellFormula(cellIn.getCellFormula());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getNumericCellValue());

                        break;


                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    }

                    {
                      CellStyle styleIn = cellIn.getCellStyle();
                      CellStyle styleOut = cellOut.getCellStyle();
                      styleOut.setDataFormat(styleIn.getDataFormat());
                    }
                    cellOut.setCellComment(cellIn.getCellComment());

                    // HSSFCellStyle cannot be cast to XSSFCellStyle
                    // cellOut.setCellStyle(cellIn.getCellStyle());
                }
            }
        }
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                outF));
        try {
            wbOut.write(out);

        } finally {
            out.close();

        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
    return outFn;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que cuando verifiques el tipo numérico agregues una validación si la celda es un número o es una fecha. Puedes usar este código:

```
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cellIn)) {
        //cambiar esto al formato que deseas de fecha
        CellStyle cellStyle = wbOut.createCellStyle();
        CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        cellStyle.setDataFormat(
            createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("d/m/yyyy h:mm"));
        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getDateCellValue());
        cellOut.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    } else {
        cellOut.setCellValue(cellIn.getNumericCellValue());
    }
    break;
```

Adaptado de: [Issue reading in a cell from Excel with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857718/1065197) y [POI - How do I set cell value to Date and apply default Excel date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794743/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell))
Echa un ojo a [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148535/how-to-read-excel-cell-having-date-with-apache-poi) también

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, le vere en un instante y le comentare mis resultados.